# Does SimpleRepository support any in-memory or other "alternative" database engines?

Tags: database, orm, subsonic, simplerepository

I am looking for options other than MS SQL Server/Express. There seem to be quite a few file based or in-memory database engines supporting some subset or dialect of SQL. Preferably it would be an engine not requiring installation at all.

Is any of them supported by SimpleRepository? Is any of them supported by ActiveRecord? Is there at least some partial support for any of these alternative engines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a Database engine, or a Query Engine, or an Object Relational Mapper?

Database engines you can use

- [MS SQL](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/default.aspx)
- [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)
- [MySql](http://www.mysql.com/)
- [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/database/index.html)
- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)
- [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)

Query Engines/ORMs, you can use

- [SubSonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/)
- [Linq-to-Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)
- [Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/)/[NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html)
- [ADO.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28VS.71%29.aspx)
- [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx)

And countless others.  If you're doing .Net development, take a look at SubSonic.  Rob Conery and the other contributors are working on some amazingly cool stuff that you might be looking for, like the SimpleRepository and ActiveRecord (almost like a rails style type of data modeling/persistence type of deal).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I already know SimpleRepository and ActiveRecord, amazing stuff! My question was regarding lightweight database engines, preferably those that are not requiring any installation. Out of the options you have listed, SQLite seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks!